# Why does the presence of a token.py cause the built-in help() to break?

Tags: python, namespaces

As a hobby/learning project, I'm writing a parser generator in Python. One of my code files is named "token.py" - which contains a couple of classes for turning plain strings into Token objects. I've just discovered that using the "help()" function from the console in Python raises an error for any module defined in a directory that contains a "token.py".

Here's a way to reproduce the error. Create a new directory with the following files:

```
/New Folder
  main.py
  token.py
```

Leave 'token.py' blank. In main.py, write a simple function - for example:

```
def test():
    pass
```

Then, in your Python console, import 'main' and call 'help(main.test)' - here's what you'll get:

```
C:\New Folder>python
Python 3.1.1 (r311:74483, Aug 17 2009, 17:02:12) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import main
>>> help(main.test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site.py", line 428, in __call__
    import pydoc
  File "C:\Python31\lib\pydoc.py", line 55, in <module>
    import sys, imp, os, re, inspect, builtins, pkgutil
  File "C:\Python31\lib\inspect.py", line 40, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Python31\lib\tokenize.py", line 37, in <module>
    COMMENT = N_TOKENS
NameError: name 'N_TOKENS' is not defined
>>>
```

If you delete the 'token.py' file, help() will behave normally. Both Python 3.1 and Python 2.5 exhibit this behavior.

Is this a known issue? If not, how do I report it?

EDIT:

Several comments state that this behavior isn't a bug. The module that defines "help" imports a module called "token" from Python's standard library. However, Python looks in the application folder before it looks in its library to find modules. In the example above, "help" tries to use my "token.py" instead of Python's, which causes the error.

Since Python is defined to exhibit this behavior, I suppose it isn't a bug. But why do people think that this behavior is acceptable? It implies that adding new modules to Python's library - even without changing existing modules - could break existing applications. It also implies that programmers are expected to have memorized the names of all modules in Python's library - how is that any less ridiculous than expecting programmers to memorize every namespace in .NET or Java? Why don't Python applications get their own namespaces? Why aren't Python standard library modules in their own namespace?

Comment: Of course you don't need to memorize all the module names. You can easily test if `myname` already exists and is in your path by doing `import myname`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your local `token.py` is being imported by `help()` instead of Python's actual `token.py`. This will occur for any number of `.py` files whose names collide with built-in modules. For example, try creating a `pydoc.py` file in the CWD and then try `help()` in Python. The `help()` function is just a built-in Python function, so it follows the same import path as any other Python code.

Comment: Why are the built-in functions' import paths relative to my application rather than Python's standard library? Doesn't this mean that if new modules are ever added to the standard library - even if existing modules remain untouched - it could still break applications? That sounds like a flaw with the runtime.

Comment: Import paths are the same for every bit of Python in the process, as defined by `sys.path`. Your code, the Python standard library, or both, might be restructured to take advantage of the (relatively recent) "absolute imports" approach -- but _that_ (if done in the standard library) would break existing applications that **do** rely on being able to substitute their code for some standard library modules (typically to enrich them), so it wouldn't be a clear win (refactoring your code, OTOH, is perfectly feasible and w/o drawbacks).

Comment: Now that we have relative imports that work properly, and take "Namespaces are a honking great idea" seriously, the **correct** approach would be for the standard library to be contained in a package. But then I don't see a way to make existing code look in that package automatically, so it would be a huge breaking change.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you choose to name your modules in a way that mimics module names defined in Python's standard library, you're fully responsible for whatever happens as a result -- other Python standard library modules are likely to rely on those that you are hiding/overriding, and if your own modules don't carefully mimic the functionality of the modules you're hiding, that's **not** a bug with Python: it's a bug with **your** code.  Of course, this applies to module [token](http://docs.python.org/library/token.html?highlight=token#module-token) as much as to any other.

If this is happening to you accidentally, and you're looking for a way to check your code for likely bugs or iffy constructs (rather than, as you say, for a way to report a nonexisting bug with the Python standard library), I think tools like [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) may be able to help.

Comment: How is it a bug with my code? Are you saying it's correct that the import paths of built-in functions are relative to my application instead of Python's standard library? See my comment on ezod's answer.

Comment: `sys.path` controls the order in which directories are checked for modules being imported -- so yes, of course it's entirely correct (and absolutely mandatory) that your directories take precedence over Python's ones, if they're listed earlier in `sys.path` (you can perfectly well control `sys.path`, e.g. by writing your own `sitecustomize.py` module in the `site-packages` directory, e.g. if you want your directories to come after Python's in import-order). Python's module (and builtin) names are **not** "reserved words": you can redefine them **if you know what you're doing**.

Comment: ...and if you **don't** know what you're doing, then, yes, it clearly **is** a bug in your code (wrong accidental choice of names).

Answer (score 1):

You can search for issues and report new ones here: http://bugs.python.org/.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug with the the help() method.  There is a module in the standard library named *token.py* which is imported by *tokenize.py* (where the error you're seeing originates from).

from tokenize.py:

```
from token import *
```

So tokenize.py expects to have a bunch of variables from the standard library token.py, but since the token.py in your working directory is actually imported they are not present which is causing the NameError (one amoungst many reasons *import ** shouldn't be used).

Comment: With an `import token` instead of the `from` statement the error message would be marginally clearer, but every other aspect of the observed behavior would be absolutely identical; so I don't agree that this is among the "many reasons" (there are many others that are much more important than error messages that may potentially confuse a beginner...;-).

Comment: Not only would (and is, in more recent versions of Python) the error message be *clearer* (easier to understand), it would be *explicit* (i.e., in conjunction with recent enhancements to `ImportError` error messages, it now *actually tells you* which file is causing the problem - and even without those enhancements, at least tells you the name of the *module* causing the problem, rather than just the one trying to `import` it).