# Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, shadowing

I have a script named `requests.py` that needs to use the third-party `requests` package.  The script either can't import the package, or can't access its functionality.

**Why isn't this working, and how do I fix it?**

Trying a plain import and then using the functionality results in an `AttributeError`:

```
import requests

res = requests.get('http://www.google.ca')
print(res)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/dev/rough/requests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Users/me/dev/rough/requests.py", line 3, in <module>
    requests.get('http://www.google.ca')
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'
```

In more recent versions of Python, the error message instead reads `AttributeError: partially initialized module 'requests' has no attribute 'get' (most likely due to a circular import)`.

Using from-import of a specific name results in an `ImportError`:

```
from requests import get

res = get('http://www.google.ca')
print(res)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests import get
  File "/Users/me/dev/rough/requests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests import get
ImportError: cannot import name 'get'
```

In more recent versions of Python, the error message instead reads `ImportError: cannot import name 'get' from partially initialized module 'requests' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/me/dev/rough/requests.py)`.

Using from-import for a module inside the package results in a different `ImportError`:

```
from requests.auth import AuthBase
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests.auth import AuthBase
  File "/Users/me/dev/rough/requests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests.auth import AuthBase
ImportError: No module named 'requests.auth'; 'requests' is not a package
```

Using a star-import and then using the functionality raises a `NameError`:

```
from requests import *

res = get('http://www.google.ca')
print(res)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests import *
  File "/Users/me/dev/rough/requests.py", line 3, in <module>
    res = get('http://www.google.ca')
NameError: name 'get' is not defined
```

---

<sup>For cases where you name your module the same as an existing one ***on purpose*** and want to handle that situation, see [How can I import from the standard library, when my project has a module with the same name? (How can I control where Python looks for modules?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584)</sup>

Comment: Please note that this is intended as a canonical answer to a common question ... please don't close as duplicate unless you're sure the other question has a better, more complete answer.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This happens because your local module named `requests.py` shadows the installed `requests` module you are trying to use.  The current directory is prepended to `sys.path`, so the local name takes precedence over the installed name.

An extra debugging tip when this comes up is to look at the Traceback carefully, and realize that the name of your script in question is matching the module you are trying to import:

Notice the name you used in your script:

```
File "/Users/me/dev/rough/requests.py", line 1, in <module>
```

The module you are trying to import: `requests`

Rename your module to something else to avoid the name collision.

Python may generate a `requests.pyc` file next to your `requests.py` file (in the `__pycache__` directory in Python 3).  Remove that as well after your rename, as the interpreter will still reference that file, re-producing the error. However, the `pyc` file in `__pycache__` *should* not affect your code if the `py` file has been removed.

In the example, renaming the file to `my_requests.py`, removing `requests.pyc`, and running again successfully prints `<Response [200]>`.

---

***Note:*** This doesn't only happen when naming your file as the module you are trying to import. This can also happen if you name your file the same as a module imported by a module you import directly. For example, having a file called ***`copy.py`*** and trying to `import pandas` from there, will give

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'copy' from 'copy'
```

That is because `pandas` imports `copy`. There is no magic solution here as you can't know all the modules' names in the world, but a rule of thumb is to try to make names of modules as unique as possible and try to change the name whenever you get such error.

Answer (score 28):

The error occurs because a user-created script has a name-clash with a library filename. Note, however, that the problem can be caused indirectly. It might take a little detective work to figure out which file is causing the problem.

For example: suppose that you have a script `mydecimal.py` that includes `import decimal`, intending to use the standard library `decimal` library for accurate floating-point calculations with decimal numbers. That doesn't cause a problem, because there is no standard library `mydecimal`. However, it so happens that `decimal` imports `numbers` (another standard library module) for internal use, so a script called `numbers.py` in your project would cause the problem.

If you still encounter problems like this after tracking own and renaming or removing the appropriate `.py` files in your project, also check for `.pyc` files [that Python uses to cache bytecode compilation when importing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215). In 3.x, these will be stored in folders with the special name `__pycache__`; it is safe to [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991015) such folders and files, and [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443) to suppress them (but you normally won't want to).

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

Problems such as this **occur when a Python source file in the project has the same name** as some external library module (either in the standard library or an installed third-party package). When attempting to `import` from the external library (which requires using an *absolute* import), **the project's own module is found instead**, causing various errors depending on the exact details.

The easiest way to fix the problem, in ordinary cases, is to rename the affected file. It may also be necessary to locate and delete any corresponding `.pyc` files. (This is perfectly safe; [the files are just a cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215) of the work that was previously done to translate Python source code into bytecode for the Python virtual machine, analogous to `.class` files in Java.)

When the project's own module is preferred, **this is because of how Python searches** for module source code for absolute imports. Depending on exactly how Python is started, the module search path defined in `sys.path` will usually **start with a path that is within the current project. Python will look there first**, before looking in any standard library or third-party library folders. This search process **does not care about the folder where the importing module is located**; any relative paths are relative to the process' [current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428), not the [importing module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499). (However, the standard library paths will normally be absolute paths, and *near the end* of `sys.path`, anyway.)

#### `AttributeError`

An `AttributeError` **occurs because the project's own module simply doesn't define** the function, class etc. that the calling code wants to use from the external library module. As a result, the `'module' object` that represents the project's module `has no attribute` with the specified name, so that's exactly what the error message claims.

In rare, unfortunate cases, the project's own module might happen to define something with the same name such that it does something different. *This can cause any kind of exception or other logical error*. For example, if the first example from the question is modified:

```
import requests

def get():
    pass

res = requests.get('http://www.google.ca')
print(res)
```

now a `TypeError` will be raised instead, because the code will attempt to call the locally-defined `get` function with the wrong number of arguments.

#### `ImportError`

Using a specific from-import causes the error to be reported differently because **the problem is now detected during the importing process itself**. In the example in the question, `from requests import get` means, instead of creating a new global name `requests` which names the module, there should be a new global name `get` which names the function from that module (the one which would be referred to as `requests.get` after a plain import). This requires looking up the `get` attribute from that module; but since the wrong module was loaded, that attribute lookup fails. More recent versions of Python report this as a probable [circular import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543).

Other import attempts can cause different `ImportError`s which complain that the imported module "is not a package". This is self-explanatory: in the example in the question, `requests` is an ordinary module (because it is defined by a source code file, `requests.py`), but the desired `requests` - defined by the third-party library - is a package (defined by several files inside a `requests` folder elsewhere, including an `__init__.py` which defines some top-level package contents that are not modules, like the `get` function).

#### `NameError`

Using a star-import, like `from requests import *`, will not fail directly - it creates global names for all the module contents. However, since the module in the question example doesn't contain anything named `get`, its attempt to star-import itself will not define that name either. Thus, a `NameError` occurs - the normal error for trying to use a global name that doesn't exist.

### Aggravating factors

1. Python's default `import` system is based on **names, not file paths**, and Python **does not distinguish** between "(driver) script files" and "library (module) files". Any Python source code can be `import`ed. Although Python caches module imports, the main script will not generally be in this cache, which means *it is perfectly capable of attempting to `import` itself*. This is what happens in the example in the question: since `requests` was not already `import`ed, there is nothing in the cache, so the attempt in the driver script (named `requests.py`) to `import requests` will search for something to import, and find the driver script (i.e., its own source file).

   This **only causes a problem at import time, if** the module tries to use that import in its own initialization, e.g. by doing a from-import. **Otherwise, the problem will be deferred**, resulting in (typically) `AttributeError` or `NameError` when trying to use the functionality. See also:

   - [What happens when using mutual or circular (cyclic) imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373)
   - [Why do circular imports seemingly work further up in the call stack but then raise an ImportError further down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279)
2. Whenever a module is loaded (i.e., imported from its source, rather than using the cache), its own top-level `import` statements run, causing more imports, recursively. Any of these indirect imports could potentially find the local code. The Python standard library **is not a package, and mostly uses absolute import** to refer to its other components. For example, as pointed out in Dave Rove's answer, attempting to import the standard library `decimal` module could fail when tried from a source file named `numbers.py`, or within a project that has such a source file.

   In [one especially pernicious case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121715), having a file named `token.py` in a project (or the current working directory, when starting up Python in interactive mode) *causes the interactive help to break*:

   ```
   $ touch token.py
   $ python
   Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47) 
   [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> help
   Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.
   >>> help()
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_sitebuiltins.py", line 102, in __call__
       import pydoc
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pydoc.py", line 66, in <module>
       import inspect
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 40, in <module>
       import linecache
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
       import tokenize
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
       from token import EXACT_TOKEN_TYPES
   ImportError: cannot import name 'EXACT_TOKEN_TYPES' from 'token' (/current/working directory/token.py)
   ```

   The traceback tells us all we need to know: calling `help` triggers a deferred import of the standard library `pydoc`, which indirectly attempts to import the standard library `token`, but finds our `token.py` which doesn't contain the appropriate name. In older versions of Python, it was even worse: `tokenize` would do a star-import from `token`, and then its top-level code would try to use a name defined there, resulting in `NameError` - and a stack trace **not mentioning** the file name `token.py`.
3. **Python can import from cached bytecode files (`.pyc`) even if the corresponding source file is renamed or deleted.** This is intended to speed up imports, but it creates an extra step to keep code directories "clean". After renaming any `.py` file to resolve a problem like this, make sure to check the bytecode cache as well.

### Solving the problem

Of course, the standard advice is simple and straightforward: just rename the `.py` files that were mistakenly imported, and delete any cached bytecode `.pyc` files for those modules. By default, in Python 3.x, the `.pyc` files for any `.py` files within a folder will be put into a subfolder with the special name `__pycache__`; in 2.x, they simply appeared alongside the corresponding `.py` files.

However, while this approach quickly solves the immediate problem for most people encountering it, the advice does not scale very well. There are a lot of potentially problematic names; while most projects will not be interested in including a source file named e.g. `os.py`, some other names might be more desirable, or harder to work around. So, here are some other useful techniques:

#### Controlling `sys.path`

Of course, since the problem is caused by `sys.path` specifying that absolute imports should look in the current project first, it can be avoided by just changing the `sys.path`.

The problematic path is described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) as a "potentially unsafe path". When using the interactive Python prompt, this will be an empty string (a relative path equivalent to `'.'`) - i.e., the current working directory for the Python process, *reflecting any changes* made by using e.g. `os.chdir`. For driver scripts started normally (`python driver.py`), it will be the directory where the script is located, as an absolute path (*not necessarily* the current working directory, since a path could be specified on the command line, like `python path/to/driver.py`). For modules run using the `-m` command-line flag, it will be the *initial* current working directory (*not necessarily* where the module is located, but also an *absolute* path that will not be affected by `os.chdir`).

**To avoid having this path in `sys.path`, do one of the following**:

- In Python 3.11 and up, [set the `PYTHONSAFEPATH` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSAFEPATH), or use the [`-P` command-line option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-P) to Python.
- In Python 3.4 and up, use the [`-I` command-line option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-I) to start in isolated mode. This, however, has several other effects: it will ignore environment variables like `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME`, and it will also skip adding the user-specific site-packages directory to the path (therefore the code will **not have access** to third-party libraries that were installed using the `--user` option for Pip).
- If all else fails, consider manually manipulating `sys.path`. This is messy and error-prone, but `sys.path` is just an ordinary list of strings with file paths, and modifying its contents will affect future `import`s. (**Do not try to replace** the list object; this will not work, because Python does not look for it by the name `sys.path`, but uses a hard-coded internal reference. It is not possible to destroy or replace that object from Python; `sys.path` is just a name that is initialized to refer to it.)

Keep in mind that removing the "unsafe" path **will prevent intentional absolute imports from working** within the package. This is inconvenient for some small projects, but also a good reason to learn proper package organization. Speaking of which:

#### Using relative imports within packages

A well-organized Python project will typically consist of one or more (usually just one) packages, stored in subfolders of the main project folder, plus one or more driver scripts placed outside of the package subfolders. **The driver scripts will typically use a single absolute import** to access the package functionality, while implementing some simple wrapper logic (e.g. to parse command-line arguments, format and report otherwise-uncaught exceptions, etc.). **The package, meanwhile, will use relative imports throughout** for its own content, and absolute import only where necessary to access *other* packages (the standard library and third-party dependencies).

For example, a project might be organized like:

```
project
├── src
│   └── my_package
│       └── x.py
│       └── y.py
│       └── z.py
└── driver.py
```

**Code in `driver.py` will use absolute import** into the package, like:

```
from my_package.x import entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    entry_point()
```

(If logic is needed to parse the command-line arguments, it should normally go in the driver rather than in the package's code.)

Then, **code inside the package will use relative imports** - so `x.py` might contain something like:

```
from .y import first_thing
from .z import second_thing

def entry_point():
    first_thing()
    second_thing()
```

**This gets the best of both worlds**: the initial absolute import sets up the top-level package so that relative imports will work, and the relative imports will avoid depending on the `sys.path` configuration. Even without taking steps to configure `sys.path`, it will typically include the folder with the driver scripts, but not any package folders; thus, this also automatically avoids import path conflicts. (An absolute import won't find the package contents unless it specifies the corresponding package path; but typically when it does, importing from the current package was intentional.)

This also avoids setting traps for the *next* project which has *this* one as a dependency. Say for example that we implement and publish an `API` package, and someone else writes `Client` which has `API` as a dependency. Since `API` code will use relative import for other `API` functionality (say, `from . import functionality`), the `Client` project's own `functionality.py` won't cause a problem.

For the initial absolute import to work, of course, the *top-level package folder* needs to be mentioned in `sys.path`. However, this is normally accomplished by *installing the package*, so it does not cause a problem.

#### Disabling bytecode caching

If a file needs to be renamed, avoiding problems with `.pyc` files will be easier if they simply don't exist in the first place. They are **not necessary**, after all; they are, again, simply intended to speed up imports on subsequent runs of the program.

To suppress `.pyc` file generation, [use the `-B` command-line option or set the `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443). (There is no built-in solution to delete all existing `.pyc` files, but this is easy enough to implement by hand using e.g. the `shutil` standard library module.)

#### Linting to avoid problematic names

Consider using third-party tools (such as IDE plugins) to warn about filenames used by the standard library or by third-party libraries in the project. In Python 3.10 and up, the full list of standard library module names is also [available as `sys.stdlib_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdlib_module_names). This includes names that might not be present in the current Python installation (e.g. OS-specific components or things that are sometimes disabled or omitted, such as Tkinter).

Answer (score 1):

just put down the import which causing error to the last

```
ex:
import requests
import flask
import numpy
```

if `import flask` is causing error then move that to bottom of the imports

```
solution:-
import requests
import numpy
import flask
```