# ImportError: Cannot import name 'SortedStringTrie'

Tags: python, importerror

```
from pytrie import SortedStringTrie as trie
t = trie(yuva=0,yuvaka=1,yuvaraaja=2,yuvati=3,varadi=4,varadigaara=5)
x = t.keys(prefix='yu')
print (x)
```

When this code is executed following error is shown

"ImportError: Cannot import name 'SortedStringTrie' ".

Comment: is your file called `pytrie.py` by any chance?

Comment: Is pytrie a library or a file that you've written?

Comment: @JustDucky pytrie is a pure Python implementation, OP might name his script  as `pytrie.py`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes it was. it is not working even if changed it to different name.

Comment: did you delete the `.pyc` file? it may be located in a `__pycache__` folder.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen There was one more file with same name which i didn't see before. Now it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 0):

please run help('modules') under your python to check whether pytrie has been installed

or run *pip* if you'd installed *pip*

Comment: if the module was not installed the error would say `ImportError: No module named 'pytrie'`, but since the OP called their script `pytrie.py` they ended up importing their own file instead of the installed module