# ImportError: No module named tag

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I am working on an NLTK project, I have successfully installed it by following the tutorial [here](http://www.nltk.org/install.html), I am using Windows 7. So to help me test my installation, I executed these commands on python:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
```

I am using Python 2.7 and is located under `C:\Python27`. Then I created a sample script (***D:\nltk-test.py***) that contains the following commands:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

text = nltk.word_tokenize("Hello world!")
print pos_tag(text)
```

The problem is when I tried to execute this using `python nltk-test.py`, I do get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nltk-test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "D:\nltk.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tag
```

I moved the file (**nltk-test.py**) inside `C:\Python27\` and it works fine, but I can't run it outside or if I placed it on a different drive.

Comment: You need to delete the `nltk.py` file, which is shadowing the installed package.

Comment: you probably have encountered [this common issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Comment: Okay I got it working. I renamed my script and removed some nltk.py. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your `D://` , there is already a nltk.py present. When you import it imports that `nltk.py` file instead of nltk module. That nltk.py file doesn't have any `tag` class, function or variable. So that's why the import error.

Solution:

rename the `nltk.py` file to something else. or move it to some other directory other than your `nltk-test.py` file's directory.