# nltk routine gives <<raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)>> in python

Tags: python, nltk

This is based on my comments in [NLTK v3.2: Unable to nltk.pos_tag()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836907/nltk-v3-2-unable-to-nltk-pos-tag/35964709?noredirect=1#comment60294185_35964709) and is based on the code supplied as an answer in [Extract city names from text using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255291/extract-city-names-from-text-using-python/36255377?noredirect=1#comment60196241_36255377)

---

I ran the code from Alvas' answer in [NLTK v3.2: Unable to nltk.pos_tag()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836907/nltk-v3-2-unable-to-nltk-pos-tag/35964709?noredirect=1#comment60294185_35964709) and the hack worked fine but when I try to run my nltk routine it still gives

```
raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type
```

… I also ran Sarim Hussain's suggestion

```
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```

successfully but no luck. – GeorgeC 2 days ago

> try upgrading your nltk, pip install -U nltk – alvas yesterday

just tried that. Still same error. On pip command I get 
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install -U nltk
Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

On running the pyhton in Idle or Pyscripter I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\SBTF\ntlk_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 110, in pos_tag
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.load(AP_MODEL_LOC)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py", line 209, in load
    self.model.weights, self.tagdict, self.classes = load(loc)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 801, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 924, in _open
    return urlopen(resource_url)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\urllib2.py", line 454, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\urllib2.py", line 1265, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>
```

– GeorgeC 16 hours ago  [above is different to what I reported earlier before restarting the computer]

> Which OS are you using?

Windows 10.

> What is your Python version?

2.7

> How did you install python?

installed via ArcGIS 10.4 and also via OSGEO4W installer (with QGIS)

> or conda? Where are you running Python? From the command prompt,
>   terminal or in some IDE?

Idle and Pyscripter, also straight from QGIS and ArcGIS.

> Are you running it through a server or a
>   cloud? Are you running it on your laptop/computer?

Laptop i7 with 16GB RAM and about 500GB+ free.

> Or in some school's
>   lab where there might be a firewall?

Nope, my own network without firewall.

> Where are you running the python
>   script? Did you have any other file name call nltk.py in your
>   directory? – alvas 16 hours ago
>
> ```
>    After upgrading to NLTK 3.2 did you use the AP_MODEL_LOC = 'file:'+str(find('taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/'+PICKLE)) hack?
> ```
>
> – alvas 16 hours ago

Yes. See code below for what I get.

> ```
>    Sorry for the multiple questions, your short comment isn't enough to >help us debug the problems, please answer each of the questions in
> ```
>
> the previous 2 comments and we'll try to find a solution afterwards.
>   Actually, it'll also be easier if yo ask another question and state
>   all the answers to those questions in the comments, it looks like it's
>   another problem. – alvas 16 hours agoHow did you install NLTK? Did you install through pip

No worries thanks for your time on this.

In the ArcGIS python module I get

```
>>> from nltk.tag import PerceptronTagger
>>> from nltk.data import find
>>> PICKLE = "averaged_perceptron_tagger.pickle"
>>> AP_MODEL_LOC = 'file:'+str(find('taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/'+PICKLE))
>>> tagger = PerceptronTagger(load=False)
>>> tagger.load(AP_MODEL_LOC)
>>> pos_tag = tagger.tag
>>> pos_tag('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split())
[('The', 'DT'), ('quick', 'JJ'), ('brown', 'NN'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumps', 'VBZ'), ('over', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('lazy', 'JJ'), ('dog', 'NN')]
>>> def extract_entity_names(t):
...     entity_names = []
... 
...     if hasattr(t, 'label') and t.label:
...         if t.label() == 'NE':
...             entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
...         else:
...             for child in t:
...                 entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(child))
... 
...     return entity_names
...     
>>> with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(line)
...         tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
...         tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
...         chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)
... 
...         entities = []
...         for tree in chunked_sentences:
...             entities.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))
... 
...         print(entities)
...         
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.txt'
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.4\\bin'
>>> os.chdir(r'E:\SBTF')
>>> os.getcwd()
'E:\\SBTF'
>>> with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(line)
...         tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
...         tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
...         chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)
... 
...         entities = []
...         for tree in chunked_sentences:
...             entities.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))
... 
...         print(entities)
...         
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined
>>> import nltk
>>> with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(line)
...         tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
...         tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
...         chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)
... 
...         entities = []
...         for tree in chunked_sentences:
...             entities.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))
... 
...         print(entities)
...         
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 110, in pos_tag
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.load(AP_MODEL_LOC)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py", line 209, in load
    self.model.weights, self.tagdict, self.classes = load(loc)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 801, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 924, in _open
    return urlopen(resource_url)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\urllib2.py", line 454, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1265, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>
```

---

String.py is in the following
[image]

Comment: Ah ha, now with the details, it seems like you have 2 different pythons installed on your computer. Can you go to powershell and do: `python -c "import sys;print sys.executable; import nltk; print nltk.__version__"` and tell us the output? Then add these lines to the top of script in ArcGIS `import sys; print sys.executable; import nltk; print nltk.__version__` and run it, what is the output for this?

Comment: Note the difference in the directories: `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages` vs `C:\python27\lib\site-packages`.

Comment: Also, try changing your own script to another name, e.g. `my_assignment.py` instead of `nltk.py`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326135/importerror-no-module-named-tag

Comment: the powershell command gives --- C:\Python27\python.exe >>3.2
the script with the name my_test.py and the code you wanted gives ---C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\python.exe >>3.2

I still get the same error as before for the rest of the code.

Comment: Just to be sure, you didn't have the error on powershell, right?

Comment: Do you have a file name `string.py` in your directory?

Comment: Actually there a few copies of strign.py in multiple directories. See updated question. Yes there is no error in powershell. The error previously was because my Avast scanner was on at the time. I turned it off and then the install worked fine. It needs to be turned off to run gdal/ogr commands as well.

Comment: Good that you got it to work! So it's a firewall problem with Avast.

Comment: Answer your own questions with some screen shots on turning on avast =)

Comment: I tried all these steps, until I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370497/nltk-unknown-url-error?noredirect=1&lq=1.  Wish I has seen that first...