# nltk 'unknown url' error

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to run a python script which uses NLTK tokenizing internally. Here is the part of code from the script which initializes NLTK

```
class NLTKTagger:
'''
class that supplies part of speech tags using NLTK
note: avoids the NLTK downloader (see __init__ method)
'''
def __init__(self):
    import nltk
    from nltk.tag import PerceptronTagger
    from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
    tokenizer_fn = os.path.abspath(resource_filename('phrasemachine.data', 'punkt.english.pickle'))
    tagger_fn = os.path.abspath(resource_filename('phrasemachine.data', 'averaged_perceptron_tagger.pickle'))
    # Load the tagger
    self.tagger = PerceptronTagger(load=False)
    self.tagger.load(tagger_fn)

    # note: nltk.word_tokenize calls the TreebankWordTokenizer, but uses the downloader.
    #       Calling the TreebankWordTokenizer like this allows skipping the downloader.
    #       It seems the TreebankWordTokenizer uses PTB tokenization = regexes. i.e. no downloads
    #       https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py#L25
    self.tokenize = TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize
    self.sent_detector = nltk.data.load(tokenizer_fn)
```

I am getting following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Uzair\Desktop\phrasemachine_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    phrasemachine.get_phrases(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\phrasemachine\phrasemachine.py", line 260, in get_phrases
    tagger = TAGGER_NAMES[tagger]()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\phrasemachine\phrasemachine.py", line 173, in get_stdeng_nltk_tagger
    tagger = NLTKTagger()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\phrasemachine\phrasemachine.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.tagger.load(tagger_fn)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py", line 209, in load
    self.model.weights, self.tagdict, self.classes = load(loc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 801, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 924, in _open
    return urlopen(resource_url)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 549, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1388, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>
```

I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 7 and NLTK 3.2.1.
I tried solutions mentioned at 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836907/nltk-v3-2-unable-to-nltk-pos-tag/35902494#35902494) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349755/nltk-routine-gives-raise-urlerrorunknown-url-type-s-type-in-python)
But none worked. Any other solution?

Comment: Reinstall with instructions from https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data loader is mistaking the `C:` prefix in your path for a protocol name like `http:`. I thought this had been fixed already... To avoid the problem, add the `file:"` protocol at the start of your path. E.g.,

```
self.tagger.load("file://"+tagger_fn)
```

(There are better ways to structure your code, but that's up to you.)

Technically this is not a bug since `nltk.data.load()` expects a URL, not a filesystem path. But really it ought to be fixed, it's not that hard to handle Windows paths...