# Cannot import graphics in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, graphics

I am writing a program in Python that uses graphics to create a house using shapes. It works on my school computer but when I tried to run this program on my macbook, I get this error

```
from graphics import GraphicsWindow
ImportError: cannot import name 'GraphicsWindow'
```

Here is my code

```
from graphics import GraphicsWindow

# Create the graphics window named win
win = GraphicsWindow(400,400)

# Create a canvas we can draw on
canvas = win.canvas()

# Draw the house. Change this if you want to draw a different style house
canvas.setColor("red")
canvas.drawRect(100,150,200,200)
# Add your python code to complete the house drawing here...

# House texture

# Vertical lines
canvas.setColor("Magenta")
canvas.drawLine(100,170,300,170)
canvas.drawLine(100,190,300,190)
canvas.drawLine(100,210,300,210)
canvas.drawLine(100,230,300,230)
canvas.drawLine(100,250,300,250)
canvas.drawLine(100,270,300,270)
canvas.drawLine(100,290,300,290)
canvas.drawLine(100,310,300,310)
canvas.drawLine(100,330,300,330)

# Horizontal lines
canvas.drawLine(120,150,120,350)
canvas.drawLine(140,150,140,350)
canvas.drawLine(160,150,160,350)
canvas.drawLine(180,150,180,350)
canvas.drawLine(200,150,200,350)
canvas.drawLine(220,150,220,350)
canvas.drawLine(240,150,240,350)
canvas.drawLine(260,150,260,350)
canvas.drawLine(280,150,280,350)

# Door
canvas.setColor("brown")
canvas.drawRect(140,250,50,100)

# Door knob
canvas.setColor("yellow")
canvas.drawOval(180,300,5,5)

# House window
canvas.setColor("green")
canvas.drawRect(220,270,50,50)
canvas.setColor("blue")
canvas.drawLine(245,270,245,320)
canvas.drawLine(220,295,270,295)

# Roof boundary lines
canvas.setColor("red")
canvas.drawLine(200,50,100,150)
canvas.drawLine(200,50,300,150)

# Roof fill
canvas.setColor("purple")
canvas.drawPoly(100,150,200,50,300,150)

# Sign saying "Welcome Home"
canvas.setColor("orange")
canvas.drawRect(150,185,101,25)
canvas.setColor("black")
canvas.drawText(155,190,"Welcome Home")

# Creates a stick person
canvas.setColor(255,204,153)
canvas.drawOval(310,250,30,30) # Head
canvas.setColor("black")
canvas.drawLine(325,320,325,280) # Body
canvas.drawLine(325,320,310,350) # Left leg
canvas.drawLine(325,320,340,350) # Right Leg
canvas.drawLine(325,300,310,300) # Left arm
canvas.drawLine(325,300,340,300) # Right arm
canvas.drawOval(317,260,3,3) # Left eye
canvas.drawOval(327,260,3,3) # Right eye
canvas.drawOval(320,270,6,3) # Mouth


# This statement will make the window stay open until its "close" button is clicked
win.wait()
```

What could be wrong? I have Python 3.5.1 installed.

Comment: Did you by any chance name your file `graphics.py`? That would mean you have accidentally imported your own file instead of the library.

Comment: No Its not named graphics.py but it is named houseprogram.py

Comment: are you able to ask your teacher for a copy of the `graphics.py` module to copy to your personal computer? It is not on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) and I can't find any obviously correct package with google.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen *That would mean you have accidentally imported your own file ...* Thats wrong. Modules found in the Pythonpath go first.

Comment: @linusg please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at, shadowing modules is a fairly common question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the graphics module your school is using originated from http://www.ezgraphics.org since it does contain a `GraphicsWindow` and your code runs correctly using the [`graphics.py`](http://www.ezgraphics.org/uploads/Software/Download/ezgraphics.py) obtained from there.

Note that you can place the `graphics.py` in the same folder as your working file or in the site-packages folder in your library.

(pretty house btw)

[image: image generated from OP's script]

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be okay, but you have to install the `graphics` module (while it's not installed, Python will raise an `ImportError`). Give `pip` a try:

```
pip install graphics
```

I think, it's because your school installed this already.

**EDIT:**

I've looked into the Python docs and `graphics` seems to be an module delivered with Python, but only wit some editions I think (I don't have it either). See this: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html. I would recommend asking your teacher how they've installed this or what Python edition they use.

**EDIT2:**

You can download the `graphics` module here: http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py. Just put the file in your site-packages folder of the Python installation.

Comment: there is no `graphics` module that can be installed via pip.

Comment: How do I install this and where?

Comment: if there was no module to import called `graphics` then the error would read `ImportError: No module named 'graphics'` but that is not the message, so this is clearly a different problem.

Comment: I asked my teacher and he said that we have 3.5.1 installed at school also.

Comment: @linusg the file you linked to has absolutely no reference to `GraphicsWindow` at all, so it is clearly not the same thing.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen In the Python doc, it says `from graphics import *
win = GraphWin()`. Also John Zelle is named at the beginning. The file at the link is from this guy.

Comment: @linusg I tried to install graphics.pyin my site-packages folder but nothing happens. I get the same error

Comment: No need to install, just put it in the folder. What error do you get? To have a `graphics.py` in site-packages and get an `ImportError` with `import graphics` is still impossible.

Comment: @linusg that is not the [official python documentation](https://www.python.org/doc/) and if the OP can import something called `GraphicsWindow` on the schools computer and there is nothing with that name in your linked file it can't be the same one used by their school.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I know the official docs. If you still do not believe me, see this: http://cpsc110.umwblogs.org/installing-python-graphics-library/, this: http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/ and this: https://www.rose-hulman.edu/Users/faculty/young/CS-Classes/resources/Python/ZelleGraphics.html.

Comment: @linusg I think that maybe, due to the extremely generic nature of the word "graphics", that maybe Reginald's school is using a different `graphics` module. The first line of code in the original question is `from graphics import GraphicsWindow` so the graphics module they are using clearly has something in it called `GraphicsWindow`, which is not present in the one you have linked to.  I have a strong feeling they are different `graphics` modules.

Answer (score -1):

Copy any `graphics.py` into your IDE Editor or directory of `file.py`.
Then use import graphics.