# Python script error No module named qgis.core

Tags: python, python-2.7, qgis

A long-distance friend created a little script for me to eventually be a plug-in inside QGIS.  But we want to try it as a stand-alone first to test and fix bugs.  He created it on a Linux machine (if that makes any difference).  When I try to run it on my Windows 7 64 using Python 2.7  I always get the

```
"ImportError: No module named qgis.core"
```

For days I have read up about this issue and to my best tried what was suggested on all those posts.  It seems I just have to set my variable paths correctly but have had no luck.  I have tried, for example various combinations (and all) the following paths:

```
"C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;"
"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis;"
"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\Python27\Lib;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\Python27\Lib\importlib;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\Python27\Lib\distutils;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\qgis\bin;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\qgis\python;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\qgis\python\plugins;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\qgis\python\qgis;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\qgis\python\qgis\gui;"
"C:\Toolbox\QGIS\apps\qgis\python\qgis\PyQt"
```

I first installed QGIS Esson (latest version) and tried running Python thru that.  Then I tried a separate Python install.  Now I tried an OSGeo464 installion with Python inside that.  Always the same error.

My friend sent me a different version that comments out the need for qgis.core showing just a simple UI and that script works OK so I would think my paths are working? (at least the gui-core?).

Can someone with patience please walk a "non-coder" thru this issue.  I would be soooo grateful as I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: Is the file you are running this code in named `qgis.py` by chance? Is so, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Comment: No, it has a different name. I also tried a simple test script I found.  It also gave the same error message, thinking maybe it was the script itself was the issue but no it must be my set up.

Comment: Is there another file in the directory you are running your code in named `qgis.py`?

Comment: No,... nothing called qgis.py.  I created a folder and have two files and named them fpm.py (this one works showing a GUI)., and fpm1.py which is the one throwing the qgis.core error.