# Django python Can not import FunctionType from module types

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am trying to use django channels and asgi to run a simple chat server. I have channels and daphne installed, but when I try to run the development server, I get the following error.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1062fdc80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yash/code/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
     fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/yash/code/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 63, in inner_run
     "layer": self.channel_layer,
  File "/Users/yash/code/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/asgi.py", line 86, in __str__
      return "%s (%s)" % (self.alias, name_that_thing(self.channel_layer))
  File "/Users/yash/code/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line     25, in name_that_thing
      return name_that_thing(thing.__class__)
  File "/Users/yash/code/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line     16, in name_that_thing
      if hasattr(thing, "__class__") and not isinstance(thing, (types.FunctionType, types.MethodType)):
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FunctionType'
```

I have checked out the last file and found that the error is with the types module. the line `import types` worked fine, but when the script trys to call `types.FunctionType` it gives an AttributeError. When I imported the script on the shell, It worked as expected

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

**EDIT**
`print(types)` outputs:
`<module 'types' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc'>`

**EDIT 2**
I started another django project with channels, cloned a repository from github. When I ran the development server after installing dependencies, It worked perfectly. The channels utils file is the exact same, so any help explaining this would help.

Comment: Can you do `print(types)` and show the result?

Comment: @knbk I posted the result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing other StackOverflow questions and I found a common bug in python scripts where a badly named file caused a import error. I looked around in the channel installation directory and found a file named `types.py` and changed this to `typer.py` and the program worked as normal. Thanks for the help.