# ImportError while importing python azure module storage.table

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, importerror

1) Module Azure-storage is installed:

```
sudo -H pip install azure-storage
```

Requirement already satisfied: azure-storage in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

2) In my python programme:

```
from azure.storage.table import TableService
```

gives me an error:

```
ImportError: No module named storage.table
```

3) However, if I open an interactive session I don't see the error:

```
sandeep@viepstesting:~$ python
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep 17 2016, 12:08:02)
[GCC 6.2.0 20160914] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from azure.storage.table import TableService
```

I went through the several post on this topic on this forum, nothing seems to work. E.g. tried setting PYTHONPATH to
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 1):

I will close this issue as I now think the problem was that i had a file named azure.py in the same directory.

It did not like the azure filename

Comment: This was exactly what happened to me.