# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'streaming_accuracy'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

```
accuracy = tf.streaming_accuracy (y_pred,y_true,name='acc')
recall = tf.streaming_recall (y_pred,y_true,name='acc')
precision = tf.streaming_precision(y_pred,y_true,name='acc')
confusion = tf.confuson_matrix(Labels, y_pred,num_classes=10,dtype=tf.float32,name='conf')
```

For the above code, I have received the same error in past few days. 
Isn't the syntax same as it is in the API documentation for tensorflow?

Comment: Is your filename named `tensorflow.py`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Comment: No! Its no tensorflow.py its autoencoder.py

Comment: Do you have file named tensorflow.py in same directory as `autoencoder.py`?

Comment: I change filenames when I save it. My last file I was working on was Tflearn_encoder.py

Comment: One more - can you `print(tf.__file__)` just before `accuracy = ...` and copy-paste an output here?

Comment: 'C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoencoder1.py", line 88, in <module>
    accuracy = tf.streaming_accuracy (y_pred,y_true,name='acc')
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'streaming_accuracy'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137352/discussion-between-will-k-and-lukasz-rogalski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this instead (in a fresh python file, I would suggest create a `/tmp/temp.py` and run that)

```
from tensorflow.contrib.metrics import streaming_accuracy
```

and if this doesn't work then

1. either there is an installation problem (In which case reinstall)
2. or you are importing the wrong tensorflow module.

Comment: Yes, this is working for me. But I would like to know why this was the case in the first place? I mean it should have imported the way I was importing it.

Comment: @WiLL_K You havn't shared your whole code so it's very difficult to say why it didn't work for your case.

Comment: @WiLL_K And what you are trying works on most systems so it's most likely that something has gone wrong on your system or you are making a coding mistake. Since my suggestion worked I would say there is a coding mistake somewhere in module naming or something.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I have solved the problem and its working for me.