# Running python networkx on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, networkx

I have the a very simple script to get started with `networkx` python module, which looks as follows:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph() 
g.add_edge('a','b',weight=0.1) 
g.add_edge('b','c',weight=1.5) 
g.add_edge('a','c',weight=1.0) 
g.add_edge('c','d',weight=2.2) 
print nx.shortest_path(g,'b','d')
```

When I run this using the command `python filename.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 1, in <module>
    import networkx as nx
  File "/home/path_to_file/filename.py", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'
```

When I run the same lines of code, not as whole, but line by line in the command line, it works completely fine as seen the screen-shot below:
[image]

What am I missing?

*P.S: I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using python version 2.7*

Comment: Is your script by any chance also named `networkx.py`?

Comment: Ah! Yes. Initially it was named as networkx.py. But I changed it to something else now.

Comment: And is there still a `networkx.pyc` around?

Comment: Got you! Thanks :) Deleted the `.pyc`, and now it is working fine.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please make your comment as a brief answer.

Comment: @Mani there are dozens of duplicates and nobody ever seems to find them; it should just be deleted.

Comment: @jonrsharpe then please mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @Mani for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at But you're not the OP, and their problem is no longer a problem, so why do you care either way?