# from traceback import format_exception_only ImportError: cannot import name 'format_exception_only'

Tags: python, nltk

I am getting error mentioned in the title. when calling the code  from command prompt. also attach the error path after the code.  I am using python 3.5.3 version. Error found when importing NLTK lib.

command:

Python Maintest.py

**Code:**

```
# file name Maintest.py
import sys
#import nltk #on commenting the code runs fine  

an_error = IndexError('tuple index out of range')
print(an_error)

def demorun():
    print("Demo code called")

def main(argv):
    print("Run the demo ")
    demorun()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

**Error:**

```
C:\samat\Sample\Python\Todo>python C:\samat\Sample\Python\Todo\MainTest.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\samat\Sample\Python\Todo\MainTest.py", line 3, in <module>


import nltk
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>


from nltk.internals import config_java
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 11, in <module>


import subprocess
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\subprocess.py", line 117, in <module>


import threading
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\threading.py", line 7, in <module>


from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>


import linecache
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>


import tokenize
  File "C:\samat\Sample\Python\Todo\tokenize.py", line 2, in <module>


from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize,word_tokenize
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>


from nltk.tokenize.mwe      import MWETokenizer
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\mwe.py", line 31, in <module>


 from nltk.util import Trie
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py", line 13, in <module>


import pydoc
  File "C:\Users\winduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\pydoc.py", line 72, in <module>


from traceback import format_exception_only

 importError: cannot import name 'format_exception_only'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Comment: Did you name your script `nltk.py`? Change the name of your script.

Comment: Hello alvas, I haven't rename nltk.py. but if i run the script in debug mode. it work fine.