# Python printing twice when importing facebook-sdk

Tags: python, facebook

Can somebody help me out with why this is happening? I have a python 3, virtualenv based environment, and I am writing some scripts with Facebook SDK.

When I write print statement before importing facebook, the print is happening only once.

[image: Print only once!]

When I write print statement after importing facebook, the print is happening twice, even though the print is written only once.

[image: Print twice!]

Comment: If you had tried to do **anything else**, you would have met [this error instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your file from `facebook.py` to something else. As it is, it is importing **itself** rather than the module.

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing facebook sdk library but instead import your own facebook.py file (which prints out date)

SOLUTION: change your facebook.py filename to something else.

TIP: try to avoid file naming that might cause conflicts with other libraries