# Error in unittest of Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-3.6

Hi i have written basic python unittest code below :

```
import unittest

class Phonebooktest(unittest.TestCase):

   def test_create_phonebook():
       print("welcome to python")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()`
```

i am getting an error :

```
25
/ 2
10>>2 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_phone_book.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\unittest\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .result import TestResult
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\unittest\result.py", line 5, in <module>
    import traceback
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\traceback.py", line 3, in <module>
    import collections
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter, eq as _eq
ImportError: cannot import name 'itemgetter'
```

Someone please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Is any of files in direcotry where `test_phone_book.py` resides is named `operator.py`?

Comment: yes there is operator.py file. i just remove that & tried it worked. may i know why this happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood you have a file that is named `operator.py` in your directory. Unfortunately, that name conflicts with Python's standard library, which has an [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

In fact, look at the last two lines, one of which says:

```
from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter, eq as _eq
    ImportError: cannot import name 'itemgetter'
```

Which suggests it tries to get `itemgetter` from `operator`, but since you have an `operator.py` file in your working directory, it tries to import `itemgetter` from that file, not Python's standard library.

Try to rename your `operator.py` to something else and see what happens.