# quandl get cmd vs. ecplipse

Tags: python, eclipse, quandl

i am trying to download some stock data.
pretty easy code:

```
import quandl
import numpy as np


data = quandl.get("FSE/ADS_X",authtoken='xxx',  collapse="monthly")
print(data.head(20).to_string())
```

when i run this in eclipse, it says

> AttributeError: module 'quandl' has no attribute 'get'

running this in the cmd, it works perfectly fine.
my eclipse project is looking a  C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe. this python installation can use quandl in the cmd.

any ideas?
thanks!!

Comment: Any chance you're masking the real quandl module by a directory with the same name?

Comment: @Pavel ahh i See. May Script is also called quandl! Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My program was called quandl.py as well so renaming solved the issue.

Comment: @Rabbid76 what? So shall i Leave the question open since the answer is a comment??