# Python turtle: object has no attribute 'Turtle'

Tags: python, module, turtle-graphics

this is my code:

```
import turtle 
e = turtle.Turtle
e.speed(10)
d = 100
angle = 140
for i in range (1, 1000):
    e.forward(d)
    e.left(angle)
    d = d - 1
```

when i run the code and this thing pop up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\TUrtle graphic.py", line 2, in <module>
    e = turtle.Turtle
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Turtle'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing installed package from script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-with-the-same-name-raises-attributeerro)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
e = turtle.Turtle
```

you need to do:

```
e = turtle.Turtle()
```

Full code:

```
import turtle

e = turtle.Turtle()
e.speed(10)
d = 100
angle = 140

for i in range(1, 1000):
    e.forward(d)
    e.left(angle)
    d = d - 1

turtle.mainloop()
```

Note that `d` will eventually become negative so your `forward` will effectively become a `backward` for the majority of the iterations.