# langdetect library import error in python 3.4.4

Tags: python

I have imported 'langdetect' library in python 3.4.4. This is working successfully in python 3.4.4 shell but when I create a new .py file then it does't work successfully. It shows that ImportError: cannot import name 'detect'.  How I solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have named your own file `langdetect.py` and then tried to `import langdetect`.  This makes it try to import itself.  Rename your file to something else, like `testdetect.py`.

Comment: I have done this but not solved. "ImportError: cannot import name 'detect'" is shown