# super error while programming a discord BOT with python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to python, and I was creating a Bot to discord by PyCharm when suddenly there was this giant error below, I already reinstalled python, tried configuring the PATHs for python 3.7 and 3.6, changed IDE and continues giving this error, can anyone help me figure out what's causing this?

error below:

```
    C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/Pichau/Documents/cursos/programacao/Discord/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pichau/Documents/cursos/programacao/Discord/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .user import User
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\user.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .utils import snowflake_time
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 17, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 41, in <module>
    __all__ = token.__all__ + ["COMMENT", "tokenize", "detect_encoding",
AttributeError: module 'token' has no attribute '__all__'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1qQb.png)

Comment: Do you have a file named `token.py` somewhere? See: https://bugs.python.org/issue21924

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [Importing installed package from script raises “AttributeError: module has no attribute” or “ImportError: cannot import name”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score -4):

I would check the code, unless it won’t let you, then you should probably put the code in notepad, and save it then delete the file, and try again. It probably is a computer error more then a coding error.

Comment: This seems ***highly*** unlikely.

Comment: How so? What I looked at the error... that’s what I found.

Comment: This is the equivalent of throwing salt over your shoulder and crossing your fingers.

Comment: I guess you could say that but from what I’m seeing it is having trouble with the code, and the library’s in it.