# Python libraries from Microsoft Azure

Tags: python, azure

I am using a python code to import azure activity log, but its giving module error below is the error

```
 from azure.monitor import MonitorClient
```

File "/home/seceon/azure.py", line 1, in 
    from azure.monitor import MonitorClient
ImportError: No module named monitor

I need help to remove this import error.

Comment: do you install the package "azure-monitor"?

Comment: yes did but the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have named your script as azure.py
This is conflicting with the installed azure-monitor module. I recommend you rename your script to something else and try running it again.
It should start working.

Answer (score 1):

It's a package `azure-monitor` you used for the Azure Service Management in the older version of Azure SDK for Python which GitHub repo tag is [`azure-monitor_0.3.1`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/azure-monitor_0.3.1). You can see it at https://pypi.org/project/azure-monitor/.

For installing it, I create a virtual environment in my current Python `3.6.7`. Here is my steps.

1. Command `virtualenv azure-monitor-test` and `cd azure-monitor-test`
2. Command `source bin/activate`
3. Command `pip install azure-monitor`
4. Run `from azure.monitor import MonitorClient` sucessfully in my Python interpreter, as the figure below.

[image]

5. Check my installed pip packages via command `pip list | grep azure`, then you will see these version of its related packages, as below.

[image]

Comment: I did the same its worked but unfortunately  worked only once. After that same module error.

Comment: My bad same module name. Thats why.

Comment: @AjayGupta Due to Python follow the order of `sys.path` to load modules and `.` always at the head of `sys.path`, so a name conflict custom module will override a real module what you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

This package is deprecated and has been replaced by azure-mgmt-monitor:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-monitor/

https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/overview/azure/monitoring

But yes, I agree with the inital answer that calling your script "azure.py" is a bad idea :)

(I work at MS in the team that releases these Azure packages for Python)