# How can I generate random numbers in python using random?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to code it using randint and got an attribute error for it.

```
import random
def generate(start,end,n):
    res=[]
    for j in range(n):
        res.append(random.randint(start,end))
    return res
start=1
end=15
n=5
print(generate(start,end,n))
```

The interpreter produced the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'
```

This code doesn't raise an error in idle.

Comment: This code works. What is the name of the `.py` file you are running this in? Did you name it *random.py*?

Comment: I did not name it random.py

Comment: First of all, try importing `random` in a Python shell. If this does not work, then you can be sure that random library is not imported properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 0):

Check your files name! In your case “random” is key word, you can not use "random" as a file name. Take care that no files are named `random.py`.

Comment: I did not name it random.py

Comment: @ShaonDebnath You may want to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52271581/9579306