# When I trying to import pygame, I get an error

Tags: python, pygame

When I try to import pygame, i get this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'

i have the 64 bit version of python (matches my computer), and im using version 3.7.2.

```
import pygame
```

just by this caused the error.

I really doubt the code has anything to do with this, but ill add it in any way.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

crash_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("crash.wav")

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

block_color = (53,115,255)

car_width = 73

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
gameIcon = pygame.image.load('carIcon.png')

pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

pause = False
#crash = True

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def crash():
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(crash_sound)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("You Crashed", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()



        button("Play Again",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15) 

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def unpause():
    global pause
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    pause = False


def paused()
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


        button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)   


def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A bit Racey", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)






def game_loop():
    global pause
    pygame.mixer.music.load('jazz.wav')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 4
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    thingCount = 1

    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause = True
                    paused()


            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, block_color)



        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car(x,y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
            crash()

        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            thing_width += (dodged * 1.2)

        if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
            print('y crossover')

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x+car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx+thing_width:
                print('x crossover')
                crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: The rest of the code is unrelated. Are you sure you have `pygame` installed?

Comment: Take a look here for an installation guide: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Please write minimal examples in your questions, not your complete code. If it fails on the first line, don't post the others

Comment: @Ofer Sadan I reinstalled pygame, the example that they gave me seemed to work but not my code.

Comment: the error is in your pygame library code, not in your script code

Comment: Did you perhaps name your script as `pygame.py`?

Comment: If you did name your script as `pygame.py`, see [Importing installed package from script raises “AttributeError: module has no attribute” or “ImportError: cannot import name”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36250353/2745495).

Comment: How did you install it (E.g pip, conda)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a specific IDE?

IDLE - Sometimes doesn't work with PyGame, but should

PyCharm - Have you tried going to *Preferences/Project: PROJECT_NAME/Project Interpreter*, then pressing the '+' icon and installing PyGame from there?

**Sorry, I would make this a comment, but I need 50 reputation**