# Python script to launch pymol on windows

Tags: python-3.x, pymol

I have installed the opensource version of pymol on windows (https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source).

To run pymol, I can open a python3.8 command prompt on windows and type the following:

```
import pymol
pymol.finish_launching()
```

This launches the pymol gui.

I'd now like to create a simple python script so that I can click the script (or convert to a windows executible using for example pyinstaller), however if I put the above commands in a script `pymol.py` and then run with:

```
python pymol.py
```

where python points to python3.8 I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialize module 'pymol' has no attribute 'finish_launching' most likely due to a circular import.
```

Why does this work on the command line python but not in a script and how can I fix this so the script runs and can be converted to a windows executible?

Comment: Try renaming the your script to something like `start_pymol.py` because Python tries to find `fnish_launching` in your script and not from the module itself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem. I had actually tried renaming the script, but fell into the second trap on the link you posted, that there was a left-over file with the name 'pymol' that the script was finding even though the script itself had a different name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)