# Running numpy from Pycharm

Tags: numpy

I am unable to run numpy in Pycharm BUT works fine in the Terminal. How do I make numpy work in Pycharm?

This is the error message I get in Pycharm

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/giridhar/PycharmProjects/numpy/testfile", line 12, in <module>
    a = np.array([1, 2, 3])   # Create a rank 1 array
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'
```

Comment: Sorry .. not Text Editor BUT Terminal ( Mac OS)

Comment: You say that it works fine in the text editor and you want to get it to work in the text editor, even if you replace that with terminal it doesn't make sense (yet) :)

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

It's quite likely that **you have a file called `numpy.py` in another directory**.

When you run `testfile.py` in your terminal, you are inside of your directory 'numpy' which does not have a file `numpy.py` and that's why it finds the correct numpy-module.

However, in PyCharm you can add directories to Sources Root (i.e. `sys.path` [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36250354/3692004)) which apparently contains a file called `numpy.py`. **Remove that directory from your `sys.path`** ([as explained by jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-content-roots.html)) and it should also work in PyCharm.

---

### Old answer (wrong!):

*As of my knowledge, the directory name does not interfere with module names unless maybe you define your directory as a package using `__init__.py`*
You need to be careful with how you name your directories. It's possible that the Python interpreter uses your **directory 'numpy'** to find the function 'array()' instead of using the PyPI numpy-module. **Re-naming that directory might fix your issue.**
So, e.g. "/Users/giridhar/PycharmProjects/my-numpy/testfile"