# AIML files with Python

Tags: python, chatbot, aiml

So I wanted to create a chatbot using python and i am , I tried this code

this is a screenshot of the code and the problem:

[image: this is a screenshot of the code and the problem]

...But I'm always having this Warning and I Don't Know Why :
WARNING: No match found for input: LOAD AIML B

Comment: Please include the code and error in the post itself as a code block, not as a screenshot. See the posting guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I see you named your file `aiml.py` and are importing a module of the same name which should mean I'd expect you to run into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at) but you don't which is weird. Just be aware of that in case it comes up.

Comment: which pip package you're using for `aiml`? there are a couple of them out there

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `botdata\standard` in the same path as you run in your Python script.

I suggest you use [python-aiml](https://pypi.org/project/python-aiml/) as it's most updated. The old `PyAIML` was last updated around 10 years ago, [link to Github](https://github.com/cdwfs/pyaiml). Steps below assuming you're a Windows user and have Anaconda environments enabled.

1. Install `pip install python-aiml`
2. Copy files from `C:\Users\your-username\Anaconda3\envs\env-name\Lib\site-packages\aiml\botdata\standard` and create a `standard` folder in your Python script's root and paste all those files.

The code you need:

```py
import aiml
k = aiml.Kernel()
k.learn("startup.xml")
k.respond("LOAD AIML B")
while True:
    k.respond(input("Enter your message: "))
```

3. Otherwise just `cd` to that `aiml` package location and keep your python script there. The screenshot below on how I loaded in my terminal and working proof.

[image: python-aiml in action]

[image: It's working]