# Flask Error When I run python program in pycharme

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

i have this error after run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/third_project/flask_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/third_project/flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Fl
ImportError: cannot import name 'Fl' from partially initialized module 'flask' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/user/PycharmProjects/third_project/flask.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

************************ the code :flask_test.py**************************

```
from flask import Flask

skills_app = Flask(__name__)

@skills_app.route("/")
def hompage():
    return "hello flask"

@skills_app.route("/about")
def about():
    return "hello flask/about"

if __name__=="__main__":
    skills_app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You named your program `flask,py`, so that's what's being found by `import flask` instead of the actual Flask module.

Comment: thnx bro but i changed the name and installed the package as it needs but same error

Comment: You may need to delete any `flask.pyc` or similar files that were generated from the incorrect import.

Comment: ooh thnx finally  yes it is done as u said by the pyc file thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Comment: Why are you importing `Fl` from the flask module? What's `Fl`?

Comment: thnk u all i had much help in your commnts