# random.choices can't be imported?

Tags: python, python-import

this may be an easy one so sorry for the post but I can't seem to get `random.choices()` to import

my code:

```
import random

scans = 100
foobar = []

for i in range(scans):
    string = 'https://'
    string.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k = url_len)) 
    string.join(random.choice(domains_list))
    foobar.append(string)
    del string
```

I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'
```

as an output in the mac-os terminal.

I have tried:

- restarting editor
- using `from random import choices` instead(alongside) of `import random`

again sorry if this seems like a spam post but I have been googling for a while and have not found a single answer.

Thanks to all! :D

Comment: Please show your *whole* code including the `import` statement. This is not a reproducible example. Also please show what output you are getting, and what output you want to get.

Comment: It would also be useful for you to paste the error you get into your question - including the whole error trace.

Comment: Hey @MarkRansom! Just did an update on it. Added the error message and more of the code.

Comment: `random.choices` was added in Python 3.6. Do you run an older version of Python? An other cause for the error might be that you called your own script `random.py`. BTW, you really don't need `del string` (`string` is a bad name for a variable anyway).

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: You shouldn't name a variable the same as a module.  That will lead to confusion and/or bugs.

Comment: `string = 'foobar'` causes the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'`. As for the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'`, that may be because you've got a file named `random.py` somewhere.

Comment: Hey everyone. Sorry for all of the confusion. I am extremely new to the stack overflow platform. I have updated the code to be within MRE specifications. Thanks!

Comment: @SyntaxTeen we need to know your Python version to be able to track down your issue, please read all the comments

Answer (score 3):

If you do your import like this, importing the function from the module:

```
from random import choices
```

Then your code needs to just refer to that function, since you haven't imported the module itself, so Python won't be aware of the module's name in your code:

```
choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = 10)
```

But if you instead import the whole module:

```
import random
```

Then your code needs to refer to both the module and the function, because the only way Python knows about the function is via the imported module:

```
random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = 10)
```

If you get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'
```

Then that could mean you might also be using an old Python version which simply doesn't have `choices`, as it was added in Python 3.6.

If that's not the case, then you possibly have a file named `random.py` that's accidentally getting imported instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at) for more details if that's the case.

But without knowing more details about your python version and local files, it's impossible to say exactly why you in particular are getting that particular error.

Another issue in your above code is this line - it's overwriting your `import string` statement, and setting `string` to an actual string instead (your string was `'foobar'` but any string would've caused the issue):

```
string = 'foobar'
```

When you refer to the `string` module right after, since you've overwritten it with the string `'foobar'`, trying to use the module at all (like `string.ascii_uppercase` for example) will result in this kind of error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'
```

Comment: But how does that fix the `AttributeError`?

Comment: Now that OP has edited in their actual error and full code, I can't reproduce the error; their code has issues, such as naming a string `string`.

Comment: @Matthias I updated my answer to reflect OP's additions.

Comment: Good edit. Upvoted.