# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6, tk-toolkit

does anyone have any idea on how can i write the inserted text to a label in a .txt file?

my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('مستلزمات البيت')

label1 = Entry(root, width=30)
label1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

e = ["-", label1]

lable2 = Label(root, text="اسم الغرض ")
lable2.grid(row=0, column=2)

f = open("house.txt", "a")


def clear():
    f.write(e[1])
    label1.delete(0, END)


f.close()

enter_btn = Button(root, width=80, padx=50, pady=50, text="تأكيد", command=clear)
enter_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

when i run it this appears :

```
File "C:\Users\yahya.ashwaq-PC\PycharmProjects\jad el jad\mostalzamat.py", line 21, in clear
    f.write(e[1])
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Entry
```

Comment: Please paste the code and error instead of using images to show it.

Comment: Please include relevant excerpts from the code and the output in the post itself rather than linking to images elsewhere.

Comment: `C:\Users\yahya.ashwaq-PC\Desktop\yahya\tkinter.py` is this file is created by you? If yes rename it to other name and try to run your code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36250353/3890632

Comment: It is better to raise another question instead of changing the question completely.  All the comments and answers given before seemed not relevant now.

Answer (score 1):

The probem here is that your file is called "tkinter.py", when you use `from tkinter import *` You just import you file... Just rename your file!

Next time you ask for help, copy and paste the code, DO NOT upload image of your code

Comment: i tried renaming and rerunning it but.....also didn't work. ok don't worry the next time it won't be an image 

Comment: Is there any file name tkinter in the same directory?

Comment: there could be a tkinter.pyc file in addition to the .py file

Answer (score -1):

Try writing this

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
```