# Partially initialized module 'csv' has no attribute 'writer' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, attributeerror

I tried many times but it showing same error, i dont know where is did mistake..

```
import csv

with open('student.csv','w',newline='') as f:
   w = csv.writer(f)
   w.writerow(['Rollno','Name','Marks'])
   w.writerow([101,'somesh',89])
   w.writerow([102,'yogesh',85])
   w.writerow([103,'akhilesh',75])
   w.writerow([874,'supreet',87])
```

Comment: What you have pasted is not legal python, the indentation is wrong.

Comment: You have most likely named this (or some other script of yours) `csv.py`, so that the `import csv` is reading that instead of the actual module with that name.

Comment: thanks  @jasonharper i gave different file name insted of csv.py , now its working,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing installed package from script raises “AttributeError: module has no attribute” or “ImportError: cannot import name”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36250353/6045800)

Answer (score 8):

This error is often related to the name of the .py file, as it is named as csv.py. When it tries to import csv, it imports its csv.py file which does not contain any csv.writer functions. This can be solved by simply changing the name of your .py file.

Answer (score 2):

Just rename your `csv.py` file to `csv_test.py` for example.