# Can't import logging module to main file

Tags: python, import

i am learning python and tried to follow the course about logging but i can't use modules:

here's the module i want to import:
helper.py

```
import logging
def helper():
    logging.info('hello from helper')
```

here is main file:
logs.py

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
import helper
helper.helper()
```

and here is what termianl says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DoggoBeatz\vsc projects\logs.py", line 10, in <module>
    helper.helper()
AttributeError: module 'helper' has no attribute 'helper'
```

Comment: You haven't imported `helper` in `logs.py`

Comment: this has nothing to do with `logging` and all with imports so why haven't You imported `helper` and maybe it has to do that the name of the module and function are the same

Comment: Please [edit] your question to expand it to a [mcve]. The code as shown would fail with a ``NameError``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing installed package from script raises “AttributeError: module has no attribute” or “ImportError: cannot import name”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Comment: i tried changing name of module and file, still the same error

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code shown. Have you checked that ``c:\Users\DoggoBeatz\vsc projects\logs.py`` is the path you expect for ``logs``? Have you checked that ``import helper`` imports the code you expect (via a ``print`` in the module or inspecting ``helper.__file__``)?

Comment: now i changed names of module and main file and terminal shows me: <function helper at 0x000001DEE537E9D0>

Comment: i tried running code in pycharm and everything works fine, i don't know why vcs shows error

Comment: so to see exactly waht my problem is i created new module named importf.py in which i just did def FunctOne(): line below print('hello) than in main file i imported the module called importf.FunctOne() and in terminal i have same atributeError