# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'collections.abc'; 'collections' is not a package

Tags: python, heroku

My code (python) works perfectly in local but not when I deploy it on Heroku.

[This is the error](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/apolesoqup.apache)

Comment: **1.** Don't post links to external sites for error messages you get. **2.** If the logs are huge (like in your case), paste the relevant parts of the log here and then a link separately, called "log" rather than _"This is the error"_. **3.** You've got a file called **`collections.py` in your `/app` folder**. So it's trying to import it from there rather than the actual python-`collections` module. Rename yours to not clash with the names of python modules. Like `my_collections.py` and retry. **4.** If you made any path/SYSPATH changes, you should mention that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a file called **`collections.py` in your `/app` folder**. So it's trying to import it from there rather than the actual python-`collections` module. Rename yours to not clash with the names of python built-in modules, like `my_collections.py`, and retry.