# AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'emojize'

Tags: python, import, error-handling, emoji

I'm starting in programming and I can't create a single emoji.

my code is:

```py
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbs_up:'))
print(emoji.emojize("Ola Mundo :sunglasses:"))
```

error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cleid\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\aulas python\aulas\a8.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbs_up:'))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'emojize'
```

what i do.

```py
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbs_up:', use_aliases=True))
```

Comment: Perhaps useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36250353/18470692.

Comment: If I remember correctly I once had one package that also used import emoji and was not this one https://pypi.org/project/emoji/ can you verify that you are using this package and an up to date version `import emoji;
print(emoji.__version__)`, further there is *no subfolder or file name emoji(.py)* in your directory.

Comment: @ouroboros1 that's a good thought, but the error message indicates it's not the same problem.  Unless there's *another* file `emoji.py` in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting in the round parentheses the command `language = 'alias'`.

```
smiley = emoji.emojize(':smile:', language='alias')
```

Comment: How is this going to fix the fact that `emojize` doesn't exist?