# assessment in python in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

hello I'm trying to create a 'CSV' file and do some functions on it but I keep facing this problem:

> writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
> AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'writer'

what is the solution this is my code:

```
import csv

with open('menu.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['item', 'price', 'category', 'rating', 'total', 'popular dish']
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
       writer.writerow('n')
        writer.writerows('s')
print(csv_file)
```

Comment: Did you name this script itself `csv.py`?

Comment: i did this is the output :partially initialized module 'csv' has no attribute 'writer' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: @RaghadYaseen - You did not answer John's question.  Read it again.  Is your answer "Yes" or "No"?

Comment: yes i did name the script and it didn't work

Comment: Well try naming it something different.  Not "csv.py".  Maybe "fred.py". Does it work now?

Comment: i did it still give :     writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'writer'

Comment: Note: "most likely due to a circular import" means that the module is trying to import itself!!

Comment: i'm trying to erase any reference but nothing work

Comment: i used  weakref() function but nothing work

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with references.  (Did ChatGPT tell you that?  It doesn't really **understand** anything!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-a-library-from-or-near-a-script-with-the-same-name-raises-attribute)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your script is importing itself.

```
$ cat csv.py
import csv

with open('menu.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['item', 'price', 'category', 'rating',
                      'total', 'popular dish']
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow('n')
        writer.writerows('s')
print(csv_file)

$ python3 csv.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/csv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import csv
  File "/tmp/csv.py", line 5, in <module>
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'csv' has no attribute 'writer' 
(most likely due to a circular import)
```

The problem is that your script is called "csv" and it is trying to import "csv".  That is the "circular import" that the error message is talking about.

(Your intention is to import the Python "csv" module ... but that is not what you are actually doing.)

Solution: rename your script:

```
$ mv csv.py foo.py
$ python3 foo.py
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='menu.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

The output is probably not what you want, but that is a different problem.

(Printing an output file is not going to show you the contents of the file.  Because it is an OUTPUT file.  If you want to see what you wrote to the file, `cat` it ... outside of Python ... or write some code to open it as an input file after you have written it and closed it.)

---

> i'm trying to erase any reference but nothing work
>
> i used weakref() function but nothing work

This problem is nothing to do with references.

Comment: thank  you so much i appreciate your help, but nothing worked i will check if there is a problem with my laptop

Comment: Please note that what is in my answer above is what I executed on my (Linux) machine.  The input commands ... and the output from running those commands.  I reproduced your error, and I showed how can be fixed.  (I don't know what else you are doing wrong ... to make it not work for you.)