# Can't import Swifter for python

Tags: python, pandas, swifter

I got installed Pandas 2.1.3 and Swifter 1.4.0.
When I try import swifter I got:

```
 AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.strings' has no attribute 'StringMethods'
```

That's is going wrong?
This version of Pandas not compatible with swifter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-a-library-from-or-near-a-script-with-the-same-name-raises-attribute)

Comment: Pandas 2.1.3 is compatible with Swifter 1.4.0. Both are the latest available versions.

Answer (score 0):

I get it, I just got many packages outdated. Usually I upgrade packages I import every day.
I just upgraded it one by one, now it's works.