# Error when trying to import shuffle in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to simply

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
```

but I am getting this error:

```
File "D:\research\pape\papertwo\Directional_Partial_Charging\hppo\hppo_noshare.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn.utils import shuffle
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\envs\wrsn\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\envs\wrsn\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\envs\wrsn\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\envs\wrsn\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 283, in <module>
    from . import csgraph
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\envs\wrsn\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\__init__.py", line 185, in <module>
    from ._laplacian import laplacian
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\envs\wrsn\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_laplacian.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\envs\wrsn\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from . import isolve, dsolve, interface, eigen, matfuncs
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\envs\wrsn\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\envs\wrsn\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import _iterative


ImportError: cannot import name '_iterative' from partially initialized module 'scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve'
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: did you check [Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-a-library-from-or-near-a-script-with-the-same-name-raises-attribute)